# Youtube video - autoplay in Facebook

Tags: facebook, video, youtube, facebook-opengraph, autoplay

I am wondering if it's possible to share a youtubevideo on facebook and make it start automatically in the timeline.
(I have also the possibility to share a landingpage with the youtube iframe and open graph metatags, but i could not find anything about autoplay.)

Or is the autoplay function only available on videos upload directly to facebook?

Answer (score 3):

you can't control the autoplay feature on your side by adding autoplay=1 or somethingelse to your video url. It depends on the user, having autoplay for videos in his feed activated or not. You can check this on your settings page --> https://www.facebook.com/settings?tab=videos

There you can find the autoplay option. Furthermore autoplay is only available for videos on facebook and not for youtube, vimeo, etc. videos.